# Wordpress Woocommerce related products with one product

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am currently designing a hobby wordpress site with Wordpress and have implemented WooCommerce. I am trying to display the related products for a product underneath the content of a product page and am looking at Wordpress's related functionality. I can see that the related_products query returns a single row but when it only returns a single product then the following WooCommerce loop fails:

```
if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div class="related products">

        <h2><?php _e( 'Related Products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
                <?php var_dump($products->the_post()); ?>
            <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </div>

<?php endif;
```

It is displaying "related products" but for a single result, it doesn't show the content and for multiple results, the rows are shown.

Is there an issue with the WooCommerce loop above or should I look at the query?

Thanks

Comment: `<?php var_dump($products->the_post()); ?>` - You call `the_post()` before you start the while loop. So for a single post result you iterate the loop and the while loop  will not start because the loop is already empty.

Comment: Check if this simple [woocommerce related products](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wt-woocommerce-related-products/) plugin helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue, my arguments for the filter were not accurate, updated them to the below and it worked:

```
$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
    'post_type'            => 'product',
    'posts_per_page'       => 14,
    'post__in'             => $related,
    'post__not_in'         => array( $product->id )
) );
```